# Como por os itens de uma lista em ordem crescente ou decrescente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, classificação

Estou tentando por os números de uma lista em ordem crescente mas o método sort() está pondo o 10 e seus múltiplos (20, 30) como sendo semelhante a ele mesmo dividido por 10. Por exemplo, no código a seguir:

```
numeros = ['1', '3', '2', '20', '4', '10', '30']  
numeros.sort()  
print(numeros)
```

Ele me retorna como resposta:

```
['1', '10', '2', '20', '3', '30', '4']
```

Em vez de:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '10', '20', '30']
```

Como esperado. Então por que isso acontece e como eu faço pra deixar eles em forma crescente? E como eu faria pra por em ordem decrescente?

Comment: Você está ordenando strings, não números, e strings são ordenadas alfabeticamente. Estou no celular e não consigo ver se já duplicata para esta pergunta, mas as respostas seriam `sort(numeros, key=int)` e `sort(numeros, key=int, reversed=True)`.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado, mas na verdade só quando eu pus:    numeros.sort(key=int) ou     numeros.sort(key=int, reverse=True . Mas tu respondeu em forma de comentário, depois bota como resposta mesmo para que eu possa sinalizar que ajudou e tal...

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Não consegui encontrar uma duplicata desta pergunta, ainda que tenho a sensação que já a vi. Por isso acho que a resposta seria util mesmo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python é uma linguagem dinâmica, o que significa que não há limitação do tipo que uma função pode receber como argumento. Ora a função pode receber uma *string*, ora pode receber um inteiro e, com isso, costuma-se fazer com que a função possa responder de forma esperada a todos. Uma implicação disso, quando analisado especialmente a função `sorted`, é que quando você passa uma lista de números, eles serão ordenados de forma crescente, mas quando passado uma lista de *strings*, será ordenado de forma alfabética. Você tem uma lista de *strings*, então a saída será alfabética, não numérica e, assim, há duas considerações a se fazer, que por sinal, são exclusivas entre si - isto é, uma ou outra:

1. Você tem uma lista de *strings* que possuem caracteres numéricos; você precisa que eles continuem sendo *strings*, pois devido a semântica do seu problema isso fará sentido e apenas deseja ordená-los de forma numérica.

Se for esta a sua situação, então você deverá utilizar o argumento `key` da função `sorted`. Através dele você indicará um objeto chamável - pode ser uma função, uma classe, um objeto que implementa `__call__`, etc - e, assim, a função o utilizará quando for analisar os valores da lista antes de ordená-los. Por padrão, esse argumento é `None` e a lista é ordenada considerando diretamente os valores; quando diferente de `None`, a lista é ordenada considerando o retorno do objeto chamável passado por `key` para cada valor da lista. Este objeto será sempre *memoizado* - aplicado *memoization* - o que significa que a função será chamada apenas uma vez para cada valor da lista, o que não afeta tanto a performance.

Como você tem uma lista de *strings* e quer ordená-las como inteiros, basta passar a classe `int` através do argumento `key`:

```
>>> sorted(numeros, key=int)
['1', '2', '3', '4', '10', '20', '30']
```

Assim, a lista será ordenada conforme o retorno de `int` para cada valor, mas o resultado permanecerá como uma lista de *strings*. Caso queira ordená-los de form,a reversa, basta informar o argumento `reverse` como verdadeiro:

```
>>> sorted(numeros, key=int, reverse=True)
['30', '20', '10', '4', '3', '2', '1']
```

Porém, se após a ordenação da lista você não precisar mais trabalhar com a lista original, prefira utilizar o método `sort` ao invés da função `sorted`:

```
numeros.sort(key=int)  # Crescente
numeros.sort(key=int, reverse=True)  # Decrescente
```

Pois o método irá apenas modificar a própria lista na memória, enquanto a função `sorted` irá gerar uma nova lista, consumindo o dobro de memória da aplicação.

2. Você tem uma lista de *strings* que possuem caracteres numéricos; não faz sentido que eles sejam *strings* e semanticamente os valores deveriam ser números inteiros - imagine uma lista de idades: a idade é um valor inteiro, não uma *string*;

Para esta situação, o recomendado a se fazer é converter os valores para inteiros e somente depois ordená-los como desejar. Para isso, necessariamente você terá que criar uma nova lista, então não há preferências entre `sorted` ou `sort`. Para evitar gasto desnecessário de memória, você pode criar um gerador para fazer a conversão das *strings* para inteiros e ordenar o próprio gerador. O gerador tem execução preguiçosa, isto é, só executa sua lógica quando necessário, assim você não terá que criar uma lista de inteiros não ordenados antes de ordená-los - se bem que criar a lista temporária e ordená-la através do método `sort` terá o mesmo resultado; use o que for mais conveniente.

Para criar o gerador de conversão da lista de *strings* em lista de inteiros, basta utilizar a função `map`:

```
numeros_inteiros = map(int, numeros)
```

E, assim, ordená-los de forma crescente ou decrescente:

```
>>> sorted(numeros_inteiros)  # Crescente
[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20, 30]

>>> sorted(numeros_inteiros, reverse=True)  # Decrescente
[30, 20, 10, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Se preferir criar a lista temporária e utilizar o método `sort`, ficaria algo como:

```
numeros = [int(numero) for numero in numeros]
numeros.sort()  # Crescente
numeros.sort(reverse=True)  # Decrescente
```

Perceba que, como comentei nas duas situações, na primeira o resultado continua sendo uma lista de *strings*, mas ordenadas de forma numérica, enquanto na segunda o resultado já será uma lista de inteiros.

Comment: tentei aplicar a minha lista [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15] e não deu certo: lista.sort(key=int) saiu [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15]

Answer (score -1):

Sem usar o `sort()` ou `sorted()`, só consegui a ordem crescente:

```
crescente = []
for c in range(0,3):
  numero = int(input("Digite um valor: "))
  if c == 0 or numero > crescente[-1]:
    crescente.append(numero)
  else:
    posição = 0
    while posição < len(crescente):
      if numero <= crescente[posição]:
        crescente.insert(posição,numero)
        break
      posição = posição + 1 
print(f"Ordem crescente -->{crescente}<--")
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).